# Conditional Formatting with second blank cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

How I can use Conditional Formatting if:

1. data in the first column.
2. forgot enter data in the second column.

[image: SO32620404 question example]

Comment: @pnuts the solution to the question might require some VBA code, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a conditional formatting using a formula, selecting your range, and use the following formula

```
=and(len($a6)>0,len($b6)=0)
```